# NetworkX shows wrong colors

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to plot a simple network with networkx using colors, however the colors i give the nodes are not shown on the graph...

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from([
    (4, {"color": "red"}),
    (5, {"color": "green"}),
])

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

draws this graph:

[image]

Why are these nodes not the color I assigned them to?

---

I am trying to reproduce the example from https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html

Comment: are you sure it uses `{'color': ...}` to change color? Maybe it is only information assigned to node - like `{"first name": "James", "last name": "Bond", "number": "007"}` - and it has nothing to do with node's color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example in documentation is misleading - and it doesn't even show image with colors.

Value `{"color": "red"}` is not used to change color but only keep extra information in node. You could use `{"first name": "James", "last name": "Bond", "number": "007"}` with the same result

To set color you have to use list when you draw them

```
nx.draw(G, node_color=['red', 'green', 'blue'], with_labels=True)
```

---

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from([
    (4, {"color": "red"}),
    (5, {"color": "green"}),
    (7, {"first name": "James", "last name": "Bond", "number": "007"}),
])

nx.draw(G, node_color=['red', 'green', 'blue'], with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

---

Or you will have to use `for`-loop to create list using data from nodes

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from([
    1,
    2,
    (4, {"color": "red"}),
    (5, {"color": "green"}),
    (7, {"first name": "James", "last name": "Bond", "number": "007"}),
    8,
    9,
   ('Hello', {"color": "red"}),
])

#color_map = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
color_map = []

for node in G:
    print(G.nodes[node])
    if 'color' in G.nodes[node]:
        color_map.append( G.nodes[node]['color'] )
    else: 
        color_map.append('blue')    
    
nx.draw(G, node_color=color_map, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from([
    (4, {"color": "red"}),
    (5, {"color": "green"}),
])

nx.draw_networkx(G, node_color=[i['color'] for i in dict(G.nodes(data=True)).values()])
```

Output:

[image]